# Apache Nutch hangs on a url during fetch cycle indefinitely

Tags: apache-http-server, threads, fetch

I am running Nutch 1.15 in distributed Hadoop mode, when it tries to fetch a file (185 MB) in this particular case, and it hangs with aborted threads. Then, in next cycles of Fetch Data, it will try to fetch same file over again, then thread hangs and abort. The Nutch will not skip over this url, but repeatedly trying to fetch the same file over and over again in the next Fetch cycles indefinitely. Is there a way for the Nutch to skip the url? Thanks!